# Can a C++ class include a member of its own type

Tags: c++, header, getter-setter

Is it possible for a C++ class to include an instance of its own type the same way we can in Java? For example, something like this:

```
public class A {
  private A a1;
  private A a2;
  
  A getA1(){
   return a1;
  }

  A getA2(){
   return a2;
  }

  void setA1(A a1){
   this.a1 = a1;
  }

  void setA2(A a2){
   this.a2 = a2;
  }
}
```

Now I want the same thing or a workaround in C++.

Comment: That depends. What is this *stuff* that you refer to? Can you be more specific about what effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706129/can-a-c-class-include-itself-as-an-member

Comment: What is the problem of doing this exactly the same way in C++? (changing the syntax accordingly of course)

Comment: Turtles all the way down.

Comment: Programming C++ in the same way that you program Java is mistaken. C++ has value semantics and does not have garbage collection. These two facts alone mean good C++ programs are stylistically very different from good Java programs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's doable in C++. But the syntax would be a little different:

1. `this->` instead of `this.`
2. `private:`/`public:` instead of `private`/`public` per member
3. remember to have `;` at the end of the class
4. `A*` as member (or `std::uniqe_ptr<A>` or `std::shared_ptr<A>` or `std::weak_ptr<A>`).

---

Items 1-3 are merely syntax. Item 4 is an essential difference between Java and C++:

- In Java an object variable is *a reference to the object* while in C++ an object variable is *a value*. This is why you can't hold in C++ a direct member of yourself, as is, **the size of the object would be infinite** *(A holding an actual value of A, holding an actual value of A, ... recursively).*

  In Java when A holds an A, it just holds *a reference* to the other A *(yes, you can still access recursively the referenced A, but it is not part of your size, you just hold a reference to it, it is stored elsewhere in memory. The addition to your size is just the size of a reference).*

  You can achieve similar semantics in C++ with *reference variables* or *pointers*, by adding `&` for a reference or `*` for a pointer:

  ```
  A& a2 = a1; // a2 is a reference to A, assigned with a reference to a1
              // note that a1 above is assumed to be also of type A&

  A* a2 = a1; // a2 is a pointer to A, assigned with the address stored in a1
              // note that a1 above is assumed to be also of type A*
  ```
- Java Garbage Collector reclaims unused memory while in C++ the programmer needs to handle that, possibly with C++ tools such as *smart pointers*.
- Java Garbage Collector reclaims unused memory via [Trace by Reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection), C++ smart pointers are based on scope lifetime. Additionally, C++ `shared_ptr` is based on [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) which has its advantages, but is subject to reference cycles possible leak of memory, which should be avoided with proper design of your code.

---

The C++ version of *"holding myself"* may look like any of the below (or variations of them), depending on the exact need:

### Option 1 - A *holds* but *does not own* a1 and a2

```
class A {
   A* a1 = nullptr;
   A* a2 = nullptr;

public: 
   A* getA1(){
      return a1;
   }

   A* getA2(){
     return a2;
   }

   void setA1(A* a1){
     this->a1 = a1;
   }

   void setA2(A* a2){
     this->a2 = a2;
   }
};
```

### Option 2 - A *owns* a1 and a2 as *unique resources*

```
class A {
   std::unique_ptr<A> a1 = nullptr;
   std::unique_ptr<A> a2 = nullptr;

public: 
   A* getA1(){
      return a1.get();
   }

   A* getA2(){
     return a2.get();
   }

   void setA1(std::unique_ptr<A> a1){
     this->a1 = std::move(a1);
   }

   void setA2(std::unique_ptr<A> a2){
     this->a2 = std::move(a2);
   }
};
```

### Option 3 - A *holds* a1 and a2 as *shared resources*<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup> need to make sure you avoid cyclic ownership leak.</sub>

```
class A {
   std::shared_ptr<A> a1 = nullptr;
   std::shared_ptr<A> a2 = nullptr;

public: 
   auto getA1(){
      return a1;
   }

   auto getA2(){
     return a2;
   }

   void setA1(std::shared_ptr<A> a1){
     this->a1 = a1;
   }

   void setA2(std::shared_ptr<A> a2){
     this->a2 = a2;
   }
};
```

### Option 4 - A *holds weak pointers* to a1 and a2<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup> the option of `std::weak_ptr` is relevant in case of possible cyclic dependency, a1 and a2 are owned elsewhere and might not be alive.</sub>

```
class A {
   std::weak_ptr<A> a1 = nullptr;
   std::weak_ptr<A> a2 = nullptr;

public: 
   std::shared_ptr<A> getA1(){
      return a1.lock();
   }

   std::shared_ptr<A> getA2(){
     return a2.lock();
   }

   void setA1(std::shared_ptr<A> a1){
     this->a1 = a1;
   }

   void setA2(std::shared_ptr<A> a2){
     this->a2 = a2;
   }
};
```

<sub>Option 4 code example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92d6004280fdc147</sub>

---

Note that using `A&` (reference to A) as a member, is not an option, as in C++ reference variables are stronger than Catholic wedding, they're for the lifetime of the variable without any way to reassign to another reference. And they must be assigned to a valid reference when born.

However, if `a1` and `a2` are known when the object is born, never change and stay alive for the duration of the object's lifetime, then the following option is also possible:

### Option 5 - A *holds references* to a1 and a2<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup> this option is mainly to show that it is possible to hold references, however in most cases a pointer option (like option 1), or a const pointer member, would be more suitable.</sub>

```
class A {
   A& a1;
   A& a2;

public:
   A(A& a1, A& a2): a1(a1), a2(a2) {}

   // using ref to self as a placeholder
   // to allow the creation of "the first A"  
   A(): a1(*this), a2(*this) {}
  
   A& getA1(){
      return a1;
   }

   A& getA2(){
      return a2;
   }
};

int main() {
   A a1;
   A a2(a1, a1);
}
```

---

### Option 5a - same as option 5 but without the empty constructor.

This option is based on the fact that [passing an object to its own constructor is legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608458/is-passing-a-c-object-into-its-own-constructor-legal).

```
class A {
   A& a1;
   A& a2;

public:
   A(A& a1, A& a2): a1(a1), a2(a2) {}

   A& getA1(){
      return a1;
   }

   A& getA2(){
      return a2;
   }
};

int main() {
   A a1(a1, a1); // legal, see note above
   A a2(a1, a1);
}
```

<sub>Code for option 5a: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d73dcc0d1783b7d</sub>

---

The last and final option, below, is mainly to present the possibility of going forward with option 5 (or 5a) and allowing the change of the reference held by A.

This option is possible since C++20. However, it is to be noted that using a pointer for this purpose would most probably be a better choice.

### Option 5b - A *holds references* to a1 and a2, and allowing set!<sup>*</sup>

<sub><sup>*</sup>since C++20, note that this option is mainly to show the possibility, pointers would probably be a better choice here.</sub>

```
class A {
   // all same as in option 5
public:
   void set(A& a1, A& a2){
      A other(a1, a2);
      // placement new that changes internal ref
      // is valid since C++20
      new (this) A(other);
   }
};
```

<sub>Code for option 5b: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43adef3bff619e99</sub>

<sub>See also: [Why can I assign a new value to a reference, and how can I make a reference refer to something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181372/why-can-i-assign-a-new-value-to-a-reference-and-how-can-i-make-a-reference-refe/63683529#63683529)</sub>

Comment: What about the members that have incomplete types?

Comment: What about the garbage collection? That's the real issue.

Comment: `A* as member`? Ok, but that requires changing the member functions. Also, what about incomplete types in the signature of the members? I wouldn't suggest *syntax* until the OP makes it clear what *semantics* they want.

Comment: @cigien what do you mean by "changing"? That code does not exist in C++ so there is nothing to change

Comment: @Slava Unless I'm misunderstanding the answer, it's suggesting what syntax changes are needed to make OP's code c++. I'm pointing out that making the members `A*` would need additional changes.

Comment: @cigien I think that the answer now reflects the possibilities and considerations, allowing the OP to rethink what is the semantics they need.

Comment: @john garbage collector is addressed now

Comment: [Option 2](https://godbolt.org/z/n6sMe9) without exposing the inner pointers.

Comment: I don't think option 5 is valid because how do you create the first A?

Comment: @DvirYitzchaki excellent point, I was tempted to say that [it is turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) - but added a _stop condition_ for _the first A_.